# QuickBooks Web Connector Authentication Failed

Tags: php, quickbooks

I am using Consolibyte's PHP Dev Kit for Quick Books and I have a VM with Quick Books installed as well as the Web connector for Quick Books. I am able to successfully add my SOAP service to the web connector but every time I request it to do an update, I get an authentication failure with the following message:

```
The request failed with an empty response.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
```

Where should I look to get more information on why?

It looks like I got past my original error but now I am getting an invalid username or password response.

```
ns1:authenticateResponse Invalid username or password, try again.
```

The QuickBooks table has the username and password straight from the example and that is what I am using in the web connector. Where is a good place to place some logging so I can understand why the framework is failing authentication?

Below is a log file:

```html
QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>
  Phoenix Courier:
  QuickBooks </title>
 <link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon"/><link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/font/fa/master.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/font/open-sans/styles.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/font/open-sans-condensed/styles.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/font/oswald/styles.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/base.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/phoenix.css"/>
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>    
 <script src="/js/psUserInterface.js"></script></head>
<body>
 <div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="container clearfix">
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:authenticateResponse><ns1:authenticateResult><ns1:string>67481fd9-4703-fae4-6d81-0ccbf770b4fa</ns1:string>
<ns1:string></ns1:string>
</ns1:authenticateResult></ns1:authenticateResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
   </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>  </div>
 </div>

<script>
PS_UI.navigation.initNavActive();
PS_UI.navigation.desktop.initNavArrows();
</script>
</body>
</html>

--.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services
```

Here is my QWC file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
 <AppName>My QuickBooks SOAP Server</AppName>
 <AppID></AppID>
 <AppURL>https://dispatch.sharp.com/</AppURL>
 <AppDescription>An example QuickBooks SOAP Server</AppDescription>
 <AppSupport>https://dispatch.phoenixcourier.com/</AppSupport>
 <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
 <OwnerID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-166DE1813D20}</OwnerID>
 <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-966DE1813D20}</FileID>
 <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
 <Notify>false</Notify>
 <Scheduler>
  <RunEveryNMinutes>10</RunEveryNMinutes>
 </Scheduler>
 <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

Comment: Have you tried searching yet? There are several questions that direct you to how to get more information/debug logs/troubleshooting. Set the Web Connector to VERBOSE mode. Post the full log. Post the code. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: I got past my original error but I am now getting an invalid user name and password. I see in the quickbooks log table it is doing an authenticate and logging in with user quick books. I enter my password in the web connector.

Comment: Well attempting to login

Comment: It looks like at one point I got a login: quickbooks in the log table but the response was invalid username or password?

Comment: And you posted your logs where exactly? What is the username/password you're using? Where did you post your .QWC file?

Comment: I posted some logs when I attempt to go through the troubleshooting process that does not work either so hmmm?

Comment: I think it may have simply been a user error I am thinking I did not have the correct App URL. Should it be mydomain.com/Quickbooks.Server.php?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work. It basically was my content headers as I found during research. I was using the cake framework. I did the following for testing.

`$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('text/xml');`